# Jquery and Ajax 404 Undefined Error

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

Hi I am developing a module in which i am sending data from javascript to drupal using jquery ajax.

but i am getting 404 error undefined.I am not able to figure out. Pls help

Here is my code

This is **tbg.js** an external js file

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'localhost/drupal/my_currenttime/10',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(jqXHR.status+textStatus + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

In my module file i am calling this js file in hook_nodeapi

```
function modulename_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) 
{
  switch($op)
  {
    case 'view':
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'modulename').'/tbgscript.js', 'module');
    break;
  }  
}
```

I have created a call back url for the ajax request in modulename_menu() hook

```
function modulename_menu() 
{
  $items['my_currenttime/%'] = array(
  '#title' => 'My custom callback',
  'description' => 'Desc',
  'page callback' => 'custom_currentTime',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

and my page call back method is

```
function custom_currentTime($args)
{
   echo "HELLO".$args;
}
```

i want to access the value $args in my module file.

Comment: I'm not an expert on modules and ajax, but - isn't the 'access callback' key missing from modulename_menu?

Comment: I think its not required. it will take default value "user_access"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the URL is wrong in your javascript.

Currently, if your site is on `http://localhost`, the page requested will be:

```
http://localhost/localhost/drupal/my_currenttime/10
```

When I suspect it should be:

```
http://localhost/drupal/my_currenttime/10
```

To fix that just add the `http://` part to the beginning of the URL variable in your JS code, or make it relative:

```
url: '/drupal/my_currenttime/10'
```